# Find index in Array of urls

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of URLs and base64 hashed data, and I want to make a function that finds the key of that element in React.js. I have made a handler as such:

```
showModalSpeceficHandler = (image) =>{
  this.state.images.forEach(function(image){
  console.log(Object.keys[image]);
})
console.log('someting')
```

The image property I pass in is the value of the given image. The way the function works now is it returns an array of the keys for each, character in the URL or base64 data. Is there a way, that I can get the index that matches the key of the given object?

Here is the way that I have declared my image objects:

```
let image= this.state.images.map(image => {
  return (
    <img 
      key={image}
      src={image}
      onClick={() => this.showModalSpeceficHandler(image)}
    />
  )
});
```

Maybe I should give another key instead, would that make my code easier and more maintainable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `map()` function also gives the index in the parameters for the callback: `list.map((value,index) => { /* your function */ })`. You could use like below:

```
let image= this.state.images.map((image,index) => {
    return <img key={`image-${index}`} src={image} 
        onClick={() =>this.showModalSpeceficHandler(image)}/>
});
```

Comment: @baileyhaldwin you're welcome! If it helps you, feel free to set my answer as solution.

Comment: I will accept in Four minuts. Also upvote my question, if you Think it was explained Well enough! Thank you!